# Why is Google maps 48M on Android 4.4.4 and 125M on Android 5.1.1?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.1-lollipop, google-maps

Why is Google maps only 48 Megabytes on Android 4.4.4, but is 125M on Android 5.1.1?  The Android 5.1.1 phone seems to have a 32-bit processor and the 4.4.4 phone seems to have a 64-bit processor from devicespecifications.com.  I would think the 64-bit phone would have the larger binary.

Comment: Main reason will be that Android 4.4 uses [Dalvik](/tags/dalvik/info), but with Android 5 and up [ART](/tags/art/info) is used, which on average needs about 25..50% more space for "pre-compiled code". Though the difference between 48M and 125M seems to exceed that – which might mean different versions (either in terms of "version numbers" or in terms of "variants" due to the different Android versions) are a second criterion.

Comment: The version numbers listed in the app settings appear to be the same.  Is there any other way to check?

Comment: I've also discovered that I can enabled ART on my phone.  I tried, but nothing seemed to change.  What I read was that it only works for the snapdragon chipset, but I think my phone has mediatek.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Izzy Two primary reasons: 1. On a 64-bit system some apps are optimized twice, generating a 32-bit odex and a 64-bit odex. 2. All libs are extracted on Android L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have root access, you can browse `/data/app` and that's the difference.

```
# Sample for Android K 4.4
com.android.vending-1.apk
com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk

# Sample for Android L 5.0/5.1
com.android.vending-1/
com.google.android.apps.maps-1/
```

And if you list the content of one of them, you'll see

```
com.google.android.apps.maps-1/:
base.apk (54MB)
lib/

com.google.android.apps.maps-1/lib/:
arm64/

com.google.android.apps.maps-1/lib/arm64/:
libcronet.59.0.3602.4.so    (4.9MB)
libgmm-jni.so    (9.4MB)
```

Also, Android 4.4 implements the old Dalvik VM, while on Android 5+, Google switched to a new VM called ART. The main difference is that Dalvik compiles apps Just-In-Time (JIT), while ART compiles Ahead-Of-Time (AOT), so more code is compiled in ART than in Dalvik. That's why this one is **really big**:

```
/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.google.android.apps.maps-1@base.apk@classes.dex    (109.5MB)
```

On Android 4.4 it's much smaller, you can find it out by yourself.